# Acknowledgement Behaviour of GCP Pub/sub messages

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm working on micro-service that contains subscriptions to a topic in GCP Pub/Sub. As multiple instances of a Microservices run on more than one host (multiple clusters on cloud), I wanted to know acknowledging behaviour of messages from subscriptions. When a subscription on one instance **receives, process and acknowledges** the message, does the same subscription on other hosts receive the message?

I expect that once the subscriber acknowledges, pub/sub doesn't further send the message, but what if two subscribers on same subscription on different hosts receives message at the same time, does it cause duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Pub/Sub delivers each published message at least once for every subscription.

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#at-least-once-delivery

If you want multiple "workers" to not receive message clones, you need to use a single subscription for all of them.

This is because for events you can have multiple systems listening on the same topic, on different subscriptions so that all the systems receive the event that something has happened.

For commands, you usually want a single system to handle them (even if split between multiple workers) so you would need a single subscription that is shared among all the workers.

By the way, your system should be [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Computer_science_meaning) in processing events/commands from a topic. The general rule of thumb is that each message is guaranteed to be received by a subscriber **at least** one time. Meaning the same system could potentially receive the same command two times.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, but i wanted to know what if two same subscription service on different instance of micro-service receives the message at the same time.
I don't want my services to process the message twice

Comment: @Nitish by default Pub/Sub guarantees at least once delivery. Meaning there are certain conditions where a message could be sent twice on the same worker (for example if the ack wasn't successfully sent back to Google Cloud). You can read about exactly once delivery here, but again I think you should make your system idempotent: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/exactly-once-delivery